# Confused about the ordering when doing a pull request on github

Tags: git

I'm working on an iOS project along with some other developers on github.  I'm pretty new to working with git on a shared project and I've tried to make sense of it, but I need some help.

What I've done so far:

1. Forked the main (original) repository
2. Cloned my fork to my local machine
3. Created a new branch to work on a specific feature
4. Committed & pushed the changes I made on the branch to my github branch

While I was working on my branch, the original repo has been continually changing as others have added to it.  So now, I'd like to do a pull request to put my changes back on to the original repository too.  This is what I've done so far to accomplish this:

1. Followed the instructions here to sync my fork to the remote upstream master (https://help.github.com/articles/syncing-a-fork).  Essentially, I added a git remote upstream of the original repo, git fetch upstream, then git merge upstream/master.

Now I'm confused about what to do from now.  At this point on my local machine, my clone (master branch) has been updated to the latest changes on the original repo, but my branch is not up to date.

Should I also update my branch with the latest changes I merged on my local master and then try a pull request?  If so, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At this point you have updated your local and remote 'master' branch to the upstream. Now you need to update your feature branch as well. Try something like:

```
git checkout feature_branch
git rebase master
# Sort out merge issues
git push origin feature_branch
```

If the upstream changes more before your pull request is addressed do the same as above, but end with `git push -f origin feature_branch` to update your branch/PR at the same time without opening a new PR.

Comment: Thank you this was exactly right! (Though I did end up with quite a few xcode project conflicts, but I guess that's another story!)